# Selecting class by Maven build profile

Tags: java, maven, ejb

I am quite new to Maven and Java EE programming all-together.

I would like to create a stub class for authentication testing which should be activated in the default Maven build profile.

Currently I have two classes with same name but in different packages. Is it possible to somehow select the correct class to use in the build phase by setting maven build profile parameters? I am also using EJB and JSF2.0 in my project and the authentication object is created in one of the beans:

```
AuthUtil util = new AuthUtil();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible, with some footwork. You will have to put your class(es) in a dependency and use the profiles in this manner:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <dependencies>
             <dependency>...</dependency>
       </dependencies>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>someotherprofile</id>
        <dependencies>
             <dependency>...</dependency>
       </dependencies>
    </profile>
 </profiles>
```

Also, the classes will have to be in the same package for this to work.

Cheers,

Comment: note that by doing this you will have no way of telling runtime which build is it... unless you provide a separate mechanism for telling that. That is why I'd just specify the implementation to be used in a property file.

Comment: It would be trivial to provide a method on `AuthUtil` to ask what "it" is. Or a profile-`<property>` to be filtered into the build.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the concrete class in a property file, and filter property files by maven build profile, so they would get different values. Property file would then be read by java code and it would be used accordingly.

Is there some reason to do this? It doesn't feel like the right way of doing things...